# Performing multiple joins while using IS NOT NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, null, conditional-statements

I have several tables that I am selecting data from. I am trying to get a list of information out of these tables only where the fields 
"interested_parties.emp_id" and "solicitation_entrys.sol_ent_id" are satisfied.

This is my query that I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
JOIN interested_parties ON (users.emp_id = interested_parties.emp_id) 
JOIN department_colors ON (department_colors.dept_id = users.emp_dept) 
JOIN solicitation_entrys ON (solicitation_entrys.sol_ent_id = interested_parties.sol_ent_id) 
WHERE IS NOT NULL (interested_parties.emp_id, solicitation_entrys.sol_ent_id)
```

The goal is to select everything from these tables, where these fields are not null. 
I'm getting #1064 errors from MySQL and I can't seem to solve the issue. Do I have to perform the if at the beginning of the select? If so, how would you do that with joins?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead

```
SELECT * FROM users 
JOIN interested_parties ON (users.emp_id = interested_parties.emp_id) 
JOIN department_colors ON (department_colors.dept_id = users.emp_dept) 
JOIN solicitation_entrys ON (solicitation_entrys.sol_ent_id = interested_parties.sol_ent_id) 
WHERE interested_parties.emp_id IS NOT NULL 
AND solicitation_entrys.sol_ent_id IS NOT NULL
```

You have to compare each field for not being null.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect. It makes sense that way too, imagine that

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL should telling you, the error is in your SQL syntax.
The WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE (interested_parties.emp_id IS NOT NULL)
AND (solicitation_entrys.sol_ent_id  IS NOT NULL)
```